# Duplicate Checkout on Checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am having an issue with woocommerce on my checkout page and I have the shopkeeper theme running on my site.

It displays the checkout fields, coupon fields, and subtotal twice.

[Here is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSv2N.png)

So far I have tried:

- Changing themes (The same issue shows)
- Deleting and re-installing woocommerce plugin and all woocommerce-related plugins

I checked my cart.php file via filezilla but am not too sure what I should be looking for.

Any sort of help would really be appreciated or if there is any sort of CSS that can quick fix it for me.

Thank-you!

=======

Comment: Did you modified the woocommerce template?

Comment: I have not :(

I am not a developer by any means so I only installed the shopkeeper template + plugins.

Comment: r u using any theme??

Comment: @tristup I am, but the problem existing between multiple themes when I switched

Comment: That means themes you are using that manipulated the woocommerce template. Please try the same by activating the basic themes like "twentyseventeen" or "twentysixteen". An let me know the result also specify the theme which you are using currently so I can give you a solution.

Comment: @tristup, Thank you for the quick response!!

I have activated twentyseventeen and it showed the same results in the checkout.

The current theme I am using is shopkeeper:
https://themeforest.net/item/shopkeeper-ecommerce-wp-theme-for-woocommerce/9553045

Comment: can you please share your url?